# JW Player - Disabling fast forward not working in Microsoft Edge/IE11/Safari

Tags: jquery, jwplayer, forward, seek

I'm using JW Player v8.10.3 and I want to disable fast forwarding in Chrome, Firefox, IE11, Microsoft Edge and Safari. The code below works in Chrome and Firefox.

To reproduce the issue, on Microsoft Edge/IE11/Safari, click on a future time at least a couple of times. Then click on a time even further into the future. The video will jump to the time that was clicked on a couple of times.

Has anyone run into this issue or has any ideas on how to solve this issue?

```
var seeking = false;
var maxPlayPosition = 0;

jwplayer().on('time', function (event) {
  if (!seeking) {
    maxPlayPosition = Math.max(event.position, maxPlayPosition);
  }
}).on('seek', function (event) {
  seeking = true;
}).on('seeked', function (event) {
  var pos = jwplayer().getPosition();

  if (pos > maxPlayPosition) {
    jwplayer().seek(maxPlayPosition);
  }

  seeking = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect your code snippet above to behave the same on all browsers, so there must be something unexpected going on. Have you verified that you do not need to force the viewer back to `maxPlayPosition` in the `on('seek')` event as well?

There is no built-in functionality in JW Player to prevent fast forwarding. The closest thing they have is to remove the controls completely so the viewer cannot seek ahead. If you choose this option, you would then need to add your own custom buttons for the functionality you do want, like play/pause, rewind, etc.